# How to make picture element accessible for each breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, picture-element

Let's say you have a picture element similar to this:

```
<picture class='my-image'>
   <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="large.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="med.jpg">
   <source srcset="small.jpg">
   <img src="small.jpg" alt="">
   <p>Accessible text</p>
</picture>
```

But let's say that the context of the image is different for each breakpoint. Perhaps at large size, the picture is of a man standing in front of a tree. But at mobile size, it's just a picture of a tree.

Sometimes, certain pictures work well at mobile sizes and other pictures don't depending on page layouts, etc.

Anyways, with the picture element you can only specify the `alt=` attribute in a single place for the entire picture element. But if the image context changes between each breakpoint, is it possible somehow to specify different `alt=` attributes? Do you have to use JavaScript for this (which may or may not be screen reader friendly)?

Comment: Right now you have no ALT. But yes, you could use JS to change the alt depending on the src

Comment: Your code does not seem to do anything in my OSX Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mjejpz9b/ (other than adding Hello as alt)

Comment: @mplungjan `src` should be `srcset` at `source` element.

Comment: Good call regarding `srcset`. Typo.

Comment: Fixed the srcset...

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps at large size, the picture is of a man standing in front of a tree. But at mobile size, it's just a picture of a tree.

It looks to me that this kind of situation appears only when using a strictly ["decorative image".](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/)

If those images are stictly decorative and you can't put them for certain reasons in CSS, then the alternative text has to be empty.

If they are not decorative images, then the easiest solution is to use two different `picture` tags which does not require any Javascript.

Comment: Let me give another example. Maybe there is an article about Barack Obama. There is a picture of him speaking on a stage. On desktop layouts, the picture is of him standing standing on stage. The alt text would be "Barack Obama talking while on stage" or something. But on mobile, maybe it's better to just have a zoomed in picture of barack talking. You can't tell he's on a stage since it's zoomed in. Each different picture is relevant to the context but would have slightly different descriptions for alt tags.

Comment: @JakeWilson The difference in this example is to give a better visual rendering to the page, not adding extra information to the content. That difference is purely decorative. The `alt` text is not intended to give the full description of the image but a replacement text (https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics-embedded-content.html#general-guidelines). I.e. Without the image being visible, what information is missing for you to understand the content?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `srcset` for `src` at `<source>` element, use `onerror` event of `<img>` element and `window.matchMedia()` to set `alt` attribute.

```
  <script>
    function handleError() {
      var sources = document.querySelectorAll("picture source");
      var img = document.querySelector("picture img");
      for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        if (window.matchMedia(sources[i].media).matches) {
          img.setAttribute("alt", sources[i].dataset.alt);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <picture class='my-image'>
    <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="large.jpg" data-alt="large">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="med.jpg" data-alt="small">
    <source srcset="small.jpg" data-alt="small">
    <img src="small.jpg" alt="" onerror="handleError()">
    <p>Accessible text</p>
  </picture>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/GwwHWujq1Nt8V33zmJLS?p=preview

Comment: Does this JavaScript work on things like screen readers though?

Comment: @JakeWilson Not sure what you mean by "screen readers"? Have you tried?

Comment: @JakeWilson Does `javascript` at Answer return expected result? Note, original Question does not mention "screen readers".